# Regex and python to remove a certain format of string

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings in the following form:

```
d = ['0.04M sodium propionate', ' 0.02M sodium cacodylate', ' 0.04M bis-tris propane', ' pH 8.0 ']
```

I want to remove `x.xxM` but keep the number following `pH`. I tried the following:

```
import re
for i in range(len(d)):
    d[i] = d[i].translate(None,'[1-9]+\.*[0-9]*M')
```

which produced the following:

```
>>> d
['4 sodium propionate', ' 2 sodium cacodylate', ' 4 bistris propane', ' pH 8 ']
```

removing the `.0` from the `pH` as well. I think `translate()` does not take order into account, right? Also, I don't understand why the `4`, `2` etc. still remain in either of the elements. How could I remove the pieces of strings strictly in the form `[1-9]+\.*[0-9]*M` (meaning that there should be a digit, maybe followed by a `.` and zero or more digits, and an `M`)?

Edit: I know realize that using regex doesn't work with `translate()`. It matches the `0`, `.`, and `M` and removes them. I guess I can try `re.search()`, find the exact piece of string, and then do `sub()`.

Comment: Have you tried using the regex module (`import re`)?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `translate`? because it's totally unfit for the job

Comment: I thought I was already using it. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I had, but I now realize that using regex is just plain wrong. What can I do instead?

Comment: the obvious thing, read the documentation for the regex module `help(re)`

Comment: When you say you have a list of strings of that form, are they mixed between concentration and pH strings, or do you actually have a list of lists, each one with some number of concentration strings and then a pH string at the end?

Comment: `re.sub("(\d\.\d+M)","",s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is regex pattern to filter out x.xxM:

```
[\d|.]+M
```

It means a string with digit(\d) or(|) dot(.) appearing more than 0 times(+) ending with M(M).

And here is the code:

```
result = [re.sub(r'[\d|.]+M',r'',i) for i in d]
# re.sub(A,B,Str) replaces all A with B in Str.
```

yielding this result:

```
[' sodium propionate', '  sodium cacodylate', '  bis-tris propane', ' pH 8.0 ']
```

Comment: Are you aware that this regex matches `|` as well?

Comment: @Jerry do we need to do `[\d\|.]+M`?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate This can be problematic even if it might not actually cause a problem when running the code. `[\d|.]+` will match a number, `|` or `.`. If you ever get badly formatted input like `12|.32M` the regex will match it. Or even `.....M` due to the way the regex is constructed.

Comment: @Jerry vertical bar '|' is an OR operator in regex. Unless it is escaped like '\ |', it would not be matched literally in any manner. The regex is not perfect since I forgot to escape dot which virtually matches any character here including vertical bar as you mentioned.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate here is a new regex and sorry for the inconvenience:                      ((\d)|[.])+M

Comment: @Hua2308 It doesn't appear to me that you know regex that well. If you do, then please explain to me why `|||||M` and the other examples are matching [here](http://ideone.com/PX4FRU).

Comment: @Hua2308 So you mean you cannot explain why `|||||M` is matching? Your previous comment is stating that it would not be matched literally in any manner unless escaped, which is not the case in the code executed in the link of my previous comment. I also included `whateverM` in the example strings to test which does not match; hence your other statement saying "I forgot to escape dot which virtually matches any character here" thus is again wrong.

Comment: @Jerry I'd not take it personally, and suggest that you read through my previous comments. Escaping plays a big role in understanding `[\d|.]+M`: `\d` is escaped representing any 0-9 digit, `|` is NOT escaped representing 'OR' operator(not literal back slash character), `.` is NOT escaped representing any single character(not literal dot character). So there is no surprise `||||M` matches, but it is because of `.` NOT `|`. Please see my updated regex `((\d)|[.])+M` as a comparison.

Comment: @Hua2308 I don't think you realise how wrong you are right now. If `.` within the regex is matching any character, why does `whateverM` not match? Your comparative regex is totally different and does not explain the first, and additionally, as per your own words, the `.` is again unescaped, so why then would `|||||M` not match?

Comment: @Jerry, per what you asked 'so why then would |||||M not match?', this statement is not correct. It matches as shown here http://refiddle.com/29ly

Comment: @Jerry, per what you asked 'why does whateverM not match?', it stands, but not for the reason you were questioning. Check this out: http://refiddle.com/29lz. My core regex is as right as I explained in my previous comment, the only thing I did wrong was using square bracket instead of parenthesis.

Comment: And fwiw, here is my two cents, there is always something to learn from anyone here.

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand. You mentioned that an unescaped `.` would match any single character and the second regex you proposed was `((\d)|([.]))+M`. That was your comparative regex that I was referring to. So that regex should have matched anything *because* the dot is unescaped, but it [*does not*](http://refiddle.com/29m2). Every character in regex is critical and using the wrong ones *will* lead to wrong results, thus wrong answers. I'm not even sure you know the difference between square brackets and parens in regex after seeing the way you defended your original regex.

Comment: This is a wrong solution as Jerry has pointed out. `[\d|.]` is a character class of digits, vertical bar `|` and dot `.`. It works for this input, but if the input contains `|`, like `0|5M xxx yyy`, then the regex also incorrectly matches. You might want to take a look at the explanation on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/oH3uL6/1

Comment: Thanks. Please refer to my updated answer: `{\d|.}` or `((\d)|[.])`

Comment: Realized that no one tell you how to write the character class correctly. As character class `[\d.]` (note that `|` should not be place inside like what you do, unless you want to include vertical bar), as alternation `(\d|[.])` (but **no one should ever do this**, since a basic regex engine will compile it into an alternation, which is slower than character class). Your syntax `{\d|.}` is simply non-sense

Comment: I don't think performance is the key concern, and if it really matters here. And personally I do not like the verbose way the same as printing out 0~100 without using for/while loop. Also you may refer to any regex syntax to see if vertical bar can or should be used in an alternation situation.

Answer (score 3):

I think your regex is almost correct, just that you should have used [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) instead:

```
import re
for i in range(len(d)):
    d[i] = re.sub(r'[0-9]+\.[0-9]*M *', '', d[i])
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/4bBr9c)

So that `d` becomes:

```
['sodium propionate', ' sodium cacodylate', ' bis-tris propane', ' pH 8.0 ']
```

I did minimum modifications to your regex, but here is what each part means:

```
[0-9]+   # Match at least 1 number (a number between 0 to 9 inclusive)
\.       # Match a literal dot
[0-9]*   # Match 0 or more numbers (0 through 9 inclusive)
M *      # Match the character 'M' and any spaces following it
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use re.search and then re.sub? You just need re.sub. You also want to do two completely different things, so it make sense to split them in two.

```
In [8]: d = ['0.04M sodium propionate', ' 0.02M sodium cacodylate', ' 0.04M bis-tris propane', ' pH 8.0 ']

In [9]: d1 = [ re.sub(r"\d\.\d\dM", "",x) for x in d ]
In [10]: d1
Out[10]: [' sodium propionate', '  sodium cacodylate', '  bis-tris propane', ' pH 8.0 ']

In [11]: d2 = [ re.sub(r"pH (\d+)\.\d+",r"pH \1", x) for x in d1 ]

In [12]: d2
Out[12]: [' sodium propionate', '  sodium cacodylate', '  bis-tris propane', ' pH 8 ']
```

Note that I used `\d`, which is shorthand for any numeral.

Answer (score 1):

Cnosider [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
>
> Return the string
>   obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of
>   pattern in string by the replacement repl.

In your case:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\d\.\d(\d).', r'\1', '0.04M sodium propionate')
'4 sodium propionate'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a quick and dirty

```
[re.sub(r'\b[.\d]+M\b', '', a).strip() for a in d]
```

which gives

```
['sodium propionate', 'sodium cacodylate', 'bis-tris propane', 'pH 8.0']
```

where `[.\d]+` matches any continuous sequence of digits and dots, `M` for the molar. The two `\b` ensures it's a word and a `strip()` to chop off excess whitespaces!